# Where to find a description of all the math functions like floorf and others?

Tags: c++, iphone, c, objective-c

math.h is not really a documentation. Is there something else that will describe these functions a but more in detail?

Comment: Sure, for example you can look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

floorf() is a variant for the floor() function, accepting and returning float values instead of double.

The [GNU Libc documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Rounding-Functions.html#index-floorf-2442) is very helpful.

The iPhone documentation also has a [man page about floor() functions](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/floorf.3.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since you indicated math.h I suppose you are using C++ so here's my currently booked marked reference

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/

Comment: Guess she's using Objective C. Look at the tags! Nevertheless, floorf() is the same for all C languages

Comment: yep she is. objective-c is right. but a.f.a.i.k. c++ can be used there as well. not sure.